# How to deal with a PHP project with public dir being placed in public dir

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Say you have a PHP Project like this:

```
/config/
/lib/
/public/ -- Only this folder is supposed to be public.
```

But it's uploaded entirely into Apaches public directory. As some users might not know what they are doing or a web-host only allows access to the public directory.

Is there a PHP/.htaccess solution for dealing with situations like this?

Preferably config and lib directories shouldn't be accessible and a URI like **/img/header.png** would still work.

The public directory would also contain a .htaccess file, would that ruin things for a mod_rewrite solution?

**EDIT:**

Haven't been able to solve this yet. Here's some more detailed information on the problem at hand.

Inside the `/public/` directory I have a `index.php` file and other public files like JavaScript, CSS and Images in their separate directories. I also have my `.htaccess` file here. This file contains this `mod_rewrite` code:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Set %{ENV:PROTO} variable, to allow rewrites to redirect with the
# appropriate schema automatically (http or https).
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:https]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:http]

# Rewrite www.example.com → example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:PROTO}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Block access to all hidden files and directories with the exception of
# the visible content from within the `/.well-known/` hidden directory.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!(^|/)\.well-known/([^./]+./?)+$" [NC]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
```

Works fine and all when the httpd's public directory is `/public/` but what I'm asking for is a way to counteract the possibility that a user might upload the project files directly into the public directory.

e.g. my directories end up as follows.

```
/public_html/config/
/public_html/lib/
/public_html/public/
```

I've tried to use a `.htaccess` file in my project root to counteract this but haven't had any luck. Even if I redirect traffic to `/public_html/public/` then the `.htaccess` in `/public_html/public/` will overwrite the `mod_rewrite` code that redirected into `/public_html/public/` to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay; here's what I've come up with. It was surprisingly simple.

The `.htaccess` file in my projects root contains this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L,PT]
```

And I appended the following to the `.htaccess` in my projects public folder.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,PT]
```

It seems to work independent of where it's uploaded now. Even if the non-public folders are there you can't access them. As all requests are sent to `index.php` that aren't files in the public folder.

Only thing I don't like is that you can still add `/public/` to the URI and get the same page. It's not like I'm going to have a second public directory in my public directory so it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can deny access to the non-public directory with a .htaccess in all of them including the directive:

```
deny from all
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put .htaccess file in each directory that you don't want to be accessible with the following content:

```
deny from all
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 403 ^/.*/(cache|config|lib|system/lib|logs|\.git|\.hg).*$
```

Comment: Don't mix Mod_rewrite with mod_alias, RedirectMatch directive is not a part of RewriteRule.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify whether the /config/ and /lib/ directories should be accessible from the LOCAL host via URL.

If you want no access whatsoever solution above from https://stackoverflow.com/users/4893165/benoit-lacherez works

```
deny from all
```

If you want access from a known IP address, network or localhost put an .htaccess file into every directory where you wan to limit access to and add the following (you have to change some numbers)

```
oder allow, deny
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
allow from YOUR.IP.ADD.RESS
```

You could also place the following line to have access from a network:

```
allow from 192.168.0.0
```

Comment: Only PHP needs access so deny from all ought to work.